# VML table-cell background image in Outlook HTML email only visible on click or resize

Tags: image, email, background, outlook, vml

I have a table cell with VML background image fallback for Outlook. It is working so far, but sometimes (I think when the image needs a little more time to be loaded from the server) the VML background is only visible when I click the concerned cell or when I resize the Outlook window or open the email via double click in a single view window.

Any hint what goes wrong here?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
<td class="background-cell-1" width="750" height="322" style="width: 750px; height: 322px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 0 none transparent; background-image: url('https://www.uponor.de/~/media/uponor-global/ecm-newsletter-2014/header-backgrounds/uponor-and-more1.jpg'); background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #0062C8; position: relative;">
<![if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width: 750px; height: 322px;" >
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://www.uponor.de/~/media/uponor-global/ecm-newsletter-2014-vml-fallbacks/used-in-template-and-template-branches/branch-uponor-and-more-1.png" color="#0062C8" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
        <div class="vml-panel-1" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border: none; ">
<![endif]>        

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 0 none transparent; width:100%;" width="100%">
[...my content...]    
</table>    

<![if gte mso 9]>
        </div>
    </v:textbox>
</v:rect>                    
<![endif]>
```

Comment: Here a demonstration: http://youtu.be/ori13Lo5kIQ

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out that this is actually an VML issue. I can confirm that if we use VBScript to replace the source of the image, it will refresh and the image displayed. So to do this in another way, you can put everything in a textbox and then put an image under that textbox. Check the code below.

```
<td background="https://www.uponor.de/~/media/uponor-global/ecm-newsletter-2014/header-backgrounds/uponor-and-more1.jpg" bgcolor="#0062C8" width="750" height="322" valign="top">  
<!--[if gte mso 9]>  
<img src="https://www.uponor.de/~/media/uponor-global/ecm-newsletter-2014/header-backgrounds/uponor-and-more1.jpg" alt="replace" height="92" width="120" border="0" style="display: block;" />  
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="false" stroke="false" style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;width:750px; height: 322px;">  
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->  
CONTENT GOES HERE  
<!--[if gte mso 9]>  
    </v:textbox>
</v:rect>  
<![endif]-->  
</td>
```

I've also written a [post](http://www.yunxiangchai.com/background-image-wont-show-up-until-we-click/) about this.

Let me know if this works for you. I know this is a pain in the ass. But I can't figure out another path to this. Maybe you can share with me your ideas.

Comment: The "post" link is broken. I guess I could find the original post here : http://www.yunxiangchai.com/background-image-wont-show-up-until-we-click/

Comment: Notice: same issue on Outlook (Version 2206 Build 16.0.15330.20260). VML v:fill color is displayed but I have to click on VML to load background image.

Comment: Thanks @ZalemCitizen for the correction. I've just edited the link to point to the right link. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Woody, have been looking for this for a week. Nothing worked till now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Could it have anything to do with some of the layout of your code not following what is given to you from the http://backgrounds.cm/ site?

```
<td background="image-name.jpg" bgcolor="#52627e" width="640" valign="top">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:640px;height:95px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="image-name.jpg" color="#52627e" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
  <div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="auto" width="100%">
        /* CONTENT */
    </table>

  </div>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
```

Maybe try formatting your code according to mine and see what happens? 
Also, is your image quite large in size?

Comment: I use exactly the same code given by backgrounds.cm. I think it has something to do with the art of rendering vml images in outlook. It seems that outlook stops rendering the image if it needs some time to be loaded from the server. When I resize the window or click any element in the email outlook seems to "re-render" the email and it becomes visible. I come to this conclusion because on the local server and the qa instance it works like a charm. It only occurs on the live server where it need some more time to be loaded from the source. We run into this issue in other projects, too.

Comment: The image itself is not very large. Only 202KB.

Comment: @ElmarHöfinghoff I know this is from a few years ago, but I have the same problem sometimes. Usually, if I close Outlook and reopen, the image will load.

But, I have to say that 202kb is pretty large image for emails. I use the Email Service Provider ExactTarget to also host my images, and they won't let me upload any images roughly >175kb. If I do need to use a large image, I have to host it elsewhere, and I'll only use it if the email device/client supports Retina Display (via CSS).

Comment: PS - this VML solution doesn't work on Windows 10 Email app emails.